# AWS RDS automatically stopping soon after it is started

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created an RDS on AWS which initially shows the status of 'available' but when I use my sql client to connect to it I receive the error:

**Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: Connection reset by peer, Authentication lapse 0 ms**

Then when I check the status of the RDS online (AWS dashboard) it says 'stopping'.

When I try to start the RDS again it's status will go from 'starting' to 'stopping' after a couple of minutes and then eventually 'stopped'. I can't find anything online referring to an RDS automatically stopping and I am somewhat a novice to AWS.

Comment: Go to CloudTrial's event history, and search for rds events. Maybe there is some automation that stops the db instance?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I found a event called 'StopDBInstance' which was referenced to my rds. The username was 'HIPComplianceWorker' who executed this. I work for a company, could it possibly be someone stopping the rds manually?

Comment: I've found the reason behind the 'StopDBInstance' in the Event Record. It seems I haven't properly tagged the RDS and therefore it's being shut down whenever I try to start it. @Marcin, you've basically lead me to the answer so how do I give you the answer for this question?

Comment: No problem. I can provide an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was found by checking [CloudTrial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/index.html) Event history. Based on the search it was identified that `StopDBInstance` was issued by `HIPComplianceWorker` user.

This probably means that there is an **automation** that checks the db instances launched and verifies if they comply with your companies policies. Your instance could be violating such policies, and it was automatically stopped.

You would have to contact your admins to check with them what kind of RDS you can use.